# How to find the access modifier of a member using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Find the access modifier of a member using java reflection

```
private final static long serialId = 1L;
protected String title;
public String FirstName;
```

I need to know which variable is private, protected and public?

Comment: [java.lang.reflect.Field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getModifiers--)

Comment: @SergeyLagutin I had a look before into that API. It returns an integer which represents the sum of access modifier values "private final static long". My question is to see whether there is an direct API to just get 'private or public' constants https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.reflect.Modifier.PRIVATE

Comment: Then look at all the `Modifier.is***` methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isPrivate-int-

Answer (score 6):

If you have a class (in the code below **Vlucht** ) then you can use the method **getDeclaredFields()**... 
then every field instance can invoke the method **getModifiers** which are explainted in the table below..

Reflection API has been the same since jdk1.5 so java8 is not relevant for reflection but more for accessing the array of fields using streams or similar..

if you really need something Human readable like :

> private static final
>
> protected  or public

then use `System.out.println(Modifier.toString(mod));`

System.out.println(Modifier.toString(mod));

```
public class Vlucht {
    private final static long serialId = 1L;
    protected String title;
    public String FirstName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Field[] reflectedClass = Vlucht.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : reflectedClass) {
        int mod = field.getModifiers();
        System.out.println(mod);
    }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For all fields in the class (assuming class is named theClass)

```
Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    int modifers = field.getModifiers();
    if (Modifier.isPrivate(modifers)) {
        System.out.println(field.getName() + " is Private");
    }
}
```

The following methods determine could also be used:

```
boolean isPrivate(Field field){
    int modifers = field.getModifiers();
    return Modifier.isPrivate(modifers);
}

boolean isProtected(Field field){
    int modifers = field.getModifiers();
    return Modifier.isPublic(modifers);
}

boolean isPublic(Field field){
    int modifers = field.getModifiers();
    return Modifier.isProtected(modifers);
}
```

Example usage (given a class called theClass)

```
Field titleField = theClass.getField("title");
boolean titleIsProtected = isProtected(titleField);
```